# TextView not appearing, Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Thank in advance for the help.

I am trying to add a vertically weighted TextView object to a LinearLayout.

```
//root container
LinearLayout rootContainer = new LinearLayout(activity);
rootContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
rootContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1f));
rootContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

//Text View
TextView instructions = new TextView(activity);
instructions.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,.7f));
instructions.setText(survey.instructions);
instructions.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
instructions.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
rootContainer.addView(instructions);
```

When I use the above code I get a blank screen.  However, if I comment out

```
instructions.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,.7f));
```

The TextView appears (albeit not the size that I want it).

From everything I've seen this this is the way to produce a weighted TextView (weighted vertically by the size of the screen).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you use
 
`instructions.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,.7f));`

Comment: That fixed it.  Though I'm not sure completely why.  If you can give an answer and explain why this works I'll accept it.

Comment: Is the reason that what I've done didn't work because I used 0 instead of 0dp like I might have if I done this in xml?

Comment: 0 in your old code will set the width of `instruction` to `0dp`

Comment: The what might be the reason what I have doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace what you have with this:

```
instructions.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.7f));
```

The reason why it was not shown on app startup was because when defining a view in java code, it defines it with pixels, so when you set the width to 0, it will certainly be invisible. It is unlike defining it in a xml layout file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think this answer is wrong, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
instructions.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,.7f));
```

sets your width of text view to 0 means that it will not be viewed try replacing 0 with some values or LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer on this question is wrong.
The reason why this is not working is because the `LinearLayout` was set with a `vertical` orientation, while the the `TextView` was constructed with a `width` weight:

```
instructions.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,.7f));
```

It should have been:

```
instructions.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, .7f));
```

Moreover, since the TextView was the only child of the LinearLayout, the `weightSum` attribute should have been set to 1 in order to achieve the 70% ratio:

```
rootContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,             ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
rootContainer.setWeightSum(1);
```

Comment: I have two LinearLayouts and I copied the wrong one.  I've corrected this.

Comment: In that case keep `instructions.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,.7f))`, but you still need the last bit: don't set the `weight` on the `LinearLayout`, but set the `weightSum` to 1, so that the `TextView` takes 70% of the parent. That should fix it.

Comment: I didn't post all of my code.  It isn't the only child that I am adding to the parent.  You're reading way too much into this.  I accepted the answer that I did because it fixed my problem.  What you're suggesting is exactly what did not work.

Comment: @N.T. weight_sum differs from layout_weight. Also weight_sum is not important. What it does is that that attribute should be put in the layout parent of the other views that have layout_weight. It is only the total layout_weight of the child views. And it actually does nothing. Hope I make it clear.

Comment: I know very much it differs. That is exactly why I mentioned that `rootContainer` (parent) should have it if you put the `layout_weight` on the `instructions`(child). And it does matter very much if it's there or not, as you obtain slightly different results if you use it vs. when you don't (that is when the children do have a `layout_weight` specified). On the code that **was** posted (I am not talking about solutions to magic code that is not in the question): `instructions` is a `TextView` and the only child of a `LinearLayout` (`rootContainer`).

Comment: If you don't put `weightSum` on `rootContainer` you would have the `TextView` occupy the whole parent space. If you set `weightSum` on the `TextView`, it will follow the 70% rule that was desired. In a nutshell, the presence or absence of the `weightSum` attribute on the parent gives different meaning to the attribute `layout_weight` on the child.